# Align rows of dataframes with different sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple `DataFrames` and they all have different sizes:

#### a

|  | Header1 | Header2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | item1 | item2 |
| 112 | item3 | item4 |

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({
  'Header1': ['item1', 'item3'],
  'Header2': ['item2', 'item4']
}).set_index(pd.Index([111, 112]))
```

#### b

|  | Header3 | Header4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | item5 | item6 |
| 111 | item7 | item8 |
| 111 | item9 | item10 |
| 112 | item11 | item12 |
| 112 | item13 | item14 |
| 112 | item15 | item16 |

```py
b = pd.DataFrame({
  'Header3': ['item5', 'item7', 'item9', 'item11', 'item13', 'item15'],
  'Header4': ['item6', 'item8', 'item10', 'item12', 'item14', 'item16']
}).set_index(pd.Index([111, 111, 111, 112,  112, 112]))
```

I would like to concatenate these two DataFrames like this:

#### c

|  | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | item1 | item2 | item5 | item6 |
| 111 | - | - | item7 | item8 |
| 111 | - | - | item9 | item10 |
| 112 | item3 | item4 | item11 | item12 |
| 112 | - | - | item13 | item14 |
| 112 | - | - | item15 | item16 |

When I add rows into the smaller DataFrames I still don't know how to line up the rows like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), which automatically takes indexes into account:

```
c = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> c
    Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4
111   item1   item2   item5   item6
111   item1   item2   item7   item8
111   item1   item2   item9  item10
112   item3   item4  item11  item12
112   item3   item4  item13  item14
112   item3   item4  item15  item16
```